# Can't run MySQL from command prompt

Tags: mysql, command-prompt

I downloaded MySQL 5.6.25 for Windowsx64 and I tried to run the command

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

to start using MySQL but it says

```
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Do I need to move MySQL to some other place? It is currently on the desktop.

**EDIT: I downloaded Xampp but now when I run that same command I get this:** 
[image]

Comment: put the folder that `mysql` is in into your `PATH`

Comment: Another solution would be running the command within the mysql's folder installation.

Comment: are you sure it is not already running in the background on port 3306. look at task mgr / services / MySQL56

Comment: @twentylemon How do I do that?

Comment: just use a pack like xampp or something to install it. Much easier than installing configuring yourself. also note that you need a space between `-u` and `root`

Comment: realize that mysql is a dll and service that runs on windows. it is not a program you run at a DOS prompt

Comment: @twentylemon I downloaded xampp but I have an error see my edit

Comment: generally the default install doesn't use a password. `mysql -u root` should work fine. if not, try not entering any password when it prompts

Comment: @twentylemon Oh it works now! Thank you. The book I was reading said to enter a password but it was using DOS prompt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to place mysql in your environment variable `PATH` in order to run it from the command prompt, if you are not in `bin` directory of mysql.

On windows 7 (should be similar for 8):

1. go to `control panel`>`system`
2. on left hand side you should see `Advanced system settings`>double click on that
3. At bottom of `system properties` you should see `Environment Variables`
4. scroll down in the bottom panel till you see `PATH` click on it
5. then click `EDIT` button underneath>opens new window `Edit system variables`
6. at the end add your path to your mysql installation bin folder like `C:\mysql\mysql5.6.23\bin;` (must separate by `;`).

[image]